# How to run a bat file using Agent SQL Server (with administrator rights)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

Please tell me, has anyone come across how to run a script / bat file as administrator through the SQL Server Agent
(Microsoft SQL Server 2016)?

I create a task in the agent (you need to clean files older than 7 days in the directory on the server) -> I want to go into steps, I create PowerShell:

```
$folderPath = "C:\backup\MSSQL\Daily"
$cutoffDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)

Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -LT $cutoffDate } | Remove-Item -Force
```

I run it - it works, but it does not delete files, because I need to run it as administrator.

I thought it would be better to run through a file.

I created a `.bat` file for deletion (the name is `DEL_OLD_BACKUP_TEST.bat`), I threw a cleaning script into it (running it manually on the server as administrator works fine) -> I set the PowerShell task in the agent

```
Start-Process -FilePath  "C:/backup/MSSQL/DEL_OLD_BACKUP_TEST.bat" -Verb runas
```

[image]

Does not clean files, although it works "Process Exit Code 0.  The step succeeded."

Do I need to run it under a specific user?

Comment: *Why* do you *need* to run it as an administrator? The Agent Service account should *not* have admin privileges on the host machine.

Comment: Because a regular user does not have the rights to delete files in the directory, hmm, perhaps the script itself in the bat file needs to be edited and somehow the cleaning on behalf of the admin needs to be registered

Comment: Why not give the SQL Server Agent service account access to do what it needs in the directory?

Comment: I tried to figure out how the service account works

I went to SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Agent:
I look at the account name - NT Service \ ....

I go to the directory with files to be deleted -> properties -> security -> I try to add a user and add the ability to modify

But, there this user does not exist and it can not be found

Hmm, perhaps this account only inside the service SQL Server, and editing on the computer is already carried out based on the one with which I connected to the database

Comment: *If* the location you are dealing with is local to the SQL Server, and you are using the default account, you will be able to give that default account access to the directory. Assuming you're in a domain, make sure the locations you are searching is the local machine (on that host), not the domain.

Comment: Thom A
you were right, I was looking for users not in the local namespace, thank you, the problem is solved, the files are deleted

Answer (score 1):

You can also use sql script to delete files.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PurgeOldFiles]
    @DaysToKeep INT,
    @FolderPath NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Enable xp_cmdshell
    EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
    RECONFIGURE;
    EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;
    RECONFIGURE;

    DECLARE @Cmd NVARCHAR(4000);
    SET @Cmd = 'FORFILES /P "' + @FolderPath + '" /S /M * /D -' + CAST(@DaysToKeep AS NVARCHAR(3)) + ' /C "CMD /C DEL @FILE"';
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @Cmd;
END
```

Create the above procedure in your db and run it through SQL Server Agent